# highchart legend lables does not take mouse events

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Sorry to not include a fiddle as the highchart chart is tied tight to my application. Earlier the mouse events were getting tracked over the legends as well as the legend labels . For some reason these labels does not take the events anymore, rather it goes to the container holding the charts. [image]

Any inputs?

Also when i try to inspect the above highlighted legend label, the parent container is highlighted instead of the label itself. The above problem is seen for other labels out of the plot area as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom-events](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) extension which allows to catch this event on legend item.

```
legend: {
        itemEvents: {
            mouseover:function(){
                console.log(this);
            }
        }
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Utx8g/413/